# Microsoft Outlook Rest API Oauth2 login uri not able to complete request

Tags: java, rest, outlook, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use the Microsoft Outlook REST API in java but am getting the following error after logging in to authenticate with OAuth2. My project is built in eclipse using maven and tomcat.

[image]
The link for the error is the following:
https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1033#error=unauthorized_client&error_description=The+client+does+not+exist.+If+you+are+the+application+developer%2c+configure+a+new+application+through+the+application+management+site+at+https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/.

I built my login uri with the following java class:

[image]

Here is what my application registration looks like:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out removing the <> around the client id fixes it